# Using jQuery .load() with aspx

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, load

So I'm fairly new to the .NET framework, but what I'm trying to do is execute the following jQuery code:

```
    $(document).on('click', 'a[data-link]', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        url = $this.data('link');
        $("#imagePreview").load("imageProcess.aspx?"+url);
```

where url holds something like "model=2k01&type=black&category=variable".
Unfortunately this doesn't work, becuase when I do something as simple as a Response.Write() in the aspx file, the div tag imagePreview doesn't do anything. However, removing the ? + url part works, but then I can't send any data over to the aspx file.  I'm doing it this way because every link a[data-link] has different data that's being sent over, and I need to find a dynamic way to achieve this.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

UPDATE:
Here is the part in my html code that is generating the url stuff:

```
<a class='modelsBlue' href = '#' data-link='model=" + $(this).find('model').text() + "&type=" + category + "'>" + $(this).find("model").text() + "</a>
```

and #image preview is in my code as:

```
<div id = "imagePreview"></div>
```

When I try to run the code above, i get the following error which seems to be coming from the jQuery.js file:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: &type=AutoEarly
```

Here is the imageProcess.aspx.cs file, which right now is just outputting all images in the directory:

```
namespace ModelMonitoring
{
    public partial class imageProcess : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("test");
            foreach (var f in Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()))
            {
                Response.Write(f);
                Response.Write("<br />");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SECOND UPDATE:
I don't get the error running in chrome or firefox, but the files are not being output.

Comment: The client side is good.

Comment: works for me. maybe post some more of your code?

Comment: In which version of browser your testing the same?

Comment: I know the client side should work fine, but see above for the error I'm getting.

Comment: Try ie 9 or google chrome as you are using html 5 and ie 8 doesn't support it

Comment: Just ran in google chrome, doesn't return error but doesn't work either.  See above

Comment: I think that the problem is not on serverside, try debug and look what you are actually passing to jquery load function. Then try replace your load("imageProcess.aspx?"+url) with your actual string and check if it goes to server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a whitespace issue. I had to add a wrapper around:

```
$(this).find('model').text()
```

to read:

```
$.trim($(this).find('model').text())
```

becuase the xml file I was reading from had whitespace around the model name.  Thanks to anyone who replied!